# pew simple way to create env with specific python version on windows

Tags: python, windows

On non-windows platform you can use pew to install a specific python version :

`pew install 3.5.0`

and then create a new virtualenv with it:

`pew new envname --python=$(pew locate_python 3.5.0)`

However on windows the first command does't work, command is not supported on this platform. Any simple alternative ?

Comment: AFAIK, there are only binary package managers such as [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a simple way.

Just install the other python version without adding it to the PATH. Say I have installed it a C:\Python34

Then, to create a virtualenv with that specific version

```
pew new nameOfEnv -p C:\\Python34\python.exe
```